# Application Class Not running, Permissions not being implemented in Lightswitch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have just completed developing a investor tracking system with lightswitch.  I created a truck load of permissions and have proceeded to check for them on both the screens and the entities.  For some reason, none of the permissions are being checked when I run the application. I have even deselected the "Granted on Debug" checkbox for the security administrator, and yet I have access to the entire application!  I have even set break point in the application class on the Screen_CanRun methods.  The system is running without invoking the breakpoints.  Where am I getting it wrong?

Comment: I would suggest including some code, as it may help people find out where everything is going wrong.

Comment: Have you checked if you have enabled Authentication? A wild guess because there's no code included.